# Id starting with 150. Data transfer between sql server & after that

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with data.i'm going to transfer data between two tables(using Insert INTO SELECT command).in the pld table id starts with 150(auto increment).When i tried to copy that data to new table.. problem.Because new table Id coloumn also Auto incremented field.

I wanted to Transfer data to Old table to new table.(removing New table Auto increment ) & after data transfer DONE.. Can i re state Auto Increment filed ?(Now NEW TABLE WITH DATA & NO AUTO INCREMENT )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to insert into new table with old id?

you can do this by use identity_insert

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [table name] ON
GO

INSERT INTO table (ID, Name) VALUES (1, 'value')
GO


SET IDENTITY_INSERT [table name] OFF
GO
```

see [identity_insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx)